# Запуск C# скрипта на VDS

Tags: c#, unity3d, tcp, vds

У меня есть игра на Unity. Имеется клиент и сервер.
Хотел бы загрузить сервер на вдс в виде C# скрипта, но поискав в интернете не нашел ответа на свой вопрос. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Уточни характеристики сервера, какая операционная система установлена?

Comment: Опять таки, какой функционал нужны ли открытые порты? Разбивай задачу на маленькие пункты и решай их.